# Possible gcc bug with C++14 polymorphic lambdas?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, clang, c++14

I've found a strange behavior using polymorphic C++14 lambdas (lambdas with `auto` in their parameters):

---

**Snippet 0:**

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> void doLambda(T&& mFn)
{
  std::forward<T>(mFn)(int{0});
}

template<typename T> void test(T&& mV)
{
    doLambda([&mV](auto mE)
    {
        std::forward<decltype(mV)>(mV);
    });
}

int main() { test(int{0}); return 0; }
```

*clang++ 3.5.1*: the snippet compiles and runs successfully.

*g++ 4.9.2*: the snippet fails to compile:

> example.cpp: In instantiation of `'test(T&&)::<lambda(auto:1)> [with auto:1 = int; T = int]'`:
>
> 5 : required from `'void doLambda(T&&) [with T = test(T&&) [with T = int]::]'`
>   13 : required from `'void test(T&&) [with T = int]'`
>   18 : required from here
>   12 : error: `'mV'` was not declared in this scope
>
> `std::forward<decltype(mV)>(mV);`
>   ^
>
> Compilation failed

---

**Snippet 1:**

The only difference from snippet 0 is that the `auto` inside the lambda was replaced to `int`.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> void doLambda(T&& mFn)
{
  std::forward<T>(mFn)(int{0});
}

template<typename T> void test(T&& mV)
{
    doLambda([&mV](int mE)
    {
        std::forward<decltype(mV)>(mV);
    });
}

int main() { test(int{0}); return 0; }
```

*clang++ 3.5.1*: the snippet compiles and runs successfully.

*g++ 4.9.2*: the snippet compiles and runs successfully.

---

**Snippet 3:**

The lambda is now called in-place. `auto` is still used.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> void test(T&& mV)
{
    [&mV](auto mE)
    {
        std::forward<decltype(mV)>(mV);
    }(int{0});
}

int main() { test(int{0}); return 0; }
```

*clang++ 3.5.1*: the snippet compiles and runs successfully.

*g++ 4.9.2*: the snippet compiles and runs successfully.

---

**Why is g++ complaining about snippet 0?** Is there anything wrong in my code? Is this a known bug or should I submit this?

Comment: Reproducing with [**GCC on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/428c36ca8344c8b4)

Comment: Obviously a bug. Doesn't reproduce on [trunk](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1FXFunvTq3KwqO8a), so I'm guessing it's been fixed.

Comment: @T.C. Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Seems to be this bug - https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61814 The example in the final comment by Jonathan Wakely compiles on trunk now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this behavior [is indeed a gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61814).